# robot_localization state transition equation

Tags: ros, navigation, ros-kinetic, robot-localization

[image: Rosanswers logo]

What is the state transition equation that is assumed in ekf_localization_node? More specifically, what is `f` in equation (1) of the [paper](http://docs.ros.org/lunar/api/robot_localization/html/_downloads/robot_localization_ias13_revised.pdf)?

I could potentially parse lines 241+ of the [implementation](https://github.com/cra-ros-pkg/robot_localization/blob/kinetic-devel/src/ekf.cpp), but that seems quite error prone and unnecessary.

My assumption, since it is used in the Husky robot, is that it assumes a differential drive robot, but I am unfamiliar with what these equations look like in 3-D. And I feel like this should really be documented somewhere.

Thanks!

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/363423/robot_localization-state-transition-equation/) by [plafer](https://answers.ros.org/users/60526/plafer/) on ROS Answers with karma: 3 on 2020-10-14

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

It uses an omnidirectional motion model. Essentially, just model the thing as a point, and apply newtons laws for positions, velocity, and acceleration in 3D. Tom Moore provides an eloquent answer to this same type of question [here](https://answers.ros.org/question/221837/robot_localization-ekf-internal-motion-model/).

---

Originally posted by [JackB](https://answers.ros.org/users/40162/jackb/) with karma: 977 on 2020-10-14

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1